# calculate how much space will text need

Tags: android, textview, android-viewpager, bounds

I need to make "pages" (most likely for use ViewPager) which will contain images and text.

For example first will have image, at image download will get image dimensions. After image  on layout will be X space left where i can display Y lenght text. Then for next page i will split rest of text into new string to be displayed. TextSize is in `dp` units.

I had idea to get how much pixels avarage letter takes and then calculate approx how many lines i can show in one page.

What would be a best way to make these calculations ?

And for starter i did letter calculation

```
 final float densityMult = ctx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    final float scaledPx = 20 * densityMult; //i guess its same as 20dp
    paint.setTextSize(scaledPx);
    final float size = paint.measureText("a");
```

Where on 480x800 3.7" screen it returns value 16.0 and on 540x960 4.0" 17.0
Is these values pixels ?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't really understand why you want to measure your text, but just like you have:

```
paint.measureText("a");
```

you can measure any string, not just characters. If you want to split your text manually (I shouldn't recommend that), you can check whenever the measure of your text is higher than the available width.

And yes, `measureText` returns the measure in `px`

Comment: yeah.. gathering more info i found very nice method breakText() http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#breakText%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20boolean,%20float,%20float%5B%5D%29, now the only problem seems to get maxWidth parameter